# Number of ways to choose at least 0 elements from n

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a practical combination of maximum n number of input pairs for example n=3:

`query=lorem&region=maharashtra&city=dombivali`

It could also be empty input meaning one special case. The following are all valid inputs but order does not matter:

`region=maharashtra&city=dombivali`

`city=dombivali`

`query=lorem&region=maharashtra`

`region=maharashtra`

`query=lorem&city=dombivali`

`query=lorem`

Order does not matter for example the inputs `query=lorem&city=dombivali` and  `city=dombivali&query=lorem`will have identical meaning.

Since the empty string is also valid input, three inputs results in 7 combinations if I am not mistaken. I look at problems of type "n choose k" but in this case it is more like "n choose none or more" or number of unique subsets from a set with n elements.

$\frac{3!}{3!(3-3)!} + \frac{3!}{2!(3-2)!} + \frac{3!}{1!(3-1)!} $
$ = 1 + 3 + 3= 7. $

Therefore the number of possible inputs from four input pairs will be

$\frac{4!}{4!(4-4)!} + \frac{4!}{3!(4-3)!} + \frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!} + \frac{4!}{1!(4-1)!} $
$ = 1 + 4 + 6 + 4= 15. $

Are my calculations correct or is there an easier way than my attempt?

Comment: For an interesting fact,  and the answer to your question,  see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628135/403337.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is the number of all possible subsets of a set having $n$ elements,  which is $2^n.$ In your examples you don't include the set itself, thus having $2^n - 1$

for 3 you get $2^3 - 1 = 7$

for 4 you get $2^4 - 1= 15$

Note that $2^n = C^0_n + C^1_n + \dots C^n_n$. You had the right intuition to count $C^k_n$, summing them up you'll simply get $2^n$