# Binomial series: why do we take $n \cdot (n-1)$ out?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Given: $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k(k-1)$. Find its closed form
 
We can multiply $(k^2-k)$ with $\binom{n}{k}$ and get: 
$\frac{n!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}$ 
Why do we take $n*(n-1)$ out: $n*(n-1)$*$\frac{(n-2)!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}$

I dont understand this step: $\frac{n!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}$ = $n*(n-1)$*$\frac{(n-2)!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}$ 
Why do we do it?

Comment: Who does that? I didn't. Seriously, what is your source for this, what's the context?

Comment: Because it allows us to progress to the next step.

Comment: If you have something like $17!$, that is the same as $17\cdot16\cdot15!$. That is all that is happening here. $n!$ is the same thing as $n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)!$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum with $\dbinom nk$ is well-known and we try to reduce the sum to this form.

Using the factorial representation,

$$\binom nkk(k-1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}k(k-1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{(n-k)!(k-2)!}=n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}.$$

Now $n(n-1)$ is constant and can be factored out of the sum and by shifting the indexes you can retrieve $\dbinom nk$.

Comment: Ahh I understand. Thank you

Comment: For the well-known sum, see my https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628135/403337